# What technique is Eddie Van Der Meer using?

Tags: guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar

In his cover of neon genesis evangelon opening, he does something throughout the song at 0:21 and other times throughout the verse. It sounds almost like a thumb slap but doing just a thumb slap doesnt get the same sound.

Song here:

Comment: Seems like a slap with thumb involving the thumb pick.

Comment: As he is picking with the thumb  ... this what we can see must be a ring on the thumb, with this he is slapping on the guitar.

Comment: He could be stopping the string with his finger tips.  this is a common technique in comping.  You create a percussive tap when setting the hand down to pull the next chord.  I am sure his thumb is being used (the pick) but possible all the finger, or palm edge, are slapping.

Comment: I have rolled back the question to revision 1. [meta discussion](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/is-it-important-for-previous-answers-and-comments-to-still-make-sense-after-an-o/3421)

Answer (score 1):

Throughout the song, he is using a [finger-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerstyle_guitar) technique with [hybrid picking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_picking#Technique). The specific technique that he uses beginning at 0:18 (which you can start to see around 0:21) is called a thumb slap, as you mentioned in the question itself and as advised by the commenters.

The thumb slap is the finger-style version of the [Slap Strum](https://www.guitarprinciples.com/guitar-principles-slap-strum/) technique, which is used to add a percussive, 'snare' sound to the guitar part.

If you are attempting to precisely replicate the exact sound that he is making in the video, then ensure that you are using a thumb-pick, firstly. His is plastic so, yours should be as well; and, you may want to even attempt to somehow match the thickness. Secondly, practice your thumb-slapping on a guitar with an acrylic face/body, as the performer is using (or purchase the exact same guitar.) Finally, really mute that bottom-string after you slap it, like he is doing...

I can't imagine why "doing just a thumb slap doesnt get the same sound," as you put it. It looks and sounds like a fairly straight-forward thumb slap, in truth...

**EDIT**

At 0:25 (OP edited the question from 0:21 at first,) the performer is utilizing a strumming style called [Rasgueado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasgueado) that is commonly used in flamenco style guitar.

Comment: At 0:25 seconds, he does more than just a normal thumb slap, I dont know how to describe it but its not a normal thumb slap

Comment: That is Rasgueado... it is a style of strumming with the fingers commonly used in flamenco. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasgueado